# Scrolling With Trackpad Locks Computer

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling, dell-latitude

I received a Dell Latitude 3340 (from 2015 I believe) with Windows 10 Pro pre-installed. I'm having a problem where whenever I two-finger scroll using the trackpad, the computer locks itself. Since the OS was pre-installed, I unfortunately do not know what 3rd party programs may have been installed on it. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: *locks itself*...you mean goes back to the sign in screen, or the computer becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Does this happen in Safe Mode?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and found a resolution. 
I noticed that my Dell laptop (e7450) running Win 10 recently auto-updated the touchpad drivers - this issue has only been happening since. To me that was kind of a smoking gun so I went to Device Manager, Selected: 
Mice and other pointing devices --> Dell Touchpad --> double clicked to open touch pad properties, slect 'Driver' tab and clicked Roll Back Driver.
My machine propoted for a restart and now works correcly again.
The driver I now have installed is 10.1207.101.109 dated 05/10/2105.
 Just for info, it looks like there is a newer driver available from Dell here: http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukbsdt1/product-support/product/latitude-e7450-ultrabook/drivers 
I have'nt tried the newer one as my touchpad works ok with the previous drivers and if it ain't broke... 
Hope this helps for your machine.

Comment: We have a fleet of Latitude 5580 laptops. This is happening on some. I have tried three things: I uninstall the driver in device manager (selecting the option to delete driver files), it automatically reinstalls it again and the problem returns. I have downloaded latest driver from Dell website. The download entry is marked as updated April 2018, however when you expand the download, latest driver date is Nov 2017. Finally when I roll back driver as you suggest, it automatically rolls back to a 2006 version. The gesture problem goes away. But touching the touchscreen still makes Windows lock!

Answer (score 0):

you may have already figured this out... but check for "Synaptics" in your "apps and features" area and uninstall that entry.  Your touchpad will continue working just fine.

Comment: Facing same problem but do not have Synaptic installed...

Comment: Note that uninstalling Synaptic's drivers will most likely kill the touchpad's gestures (including scrolling) until you reinstall the drivers or find some other driver that happens to be compatible (Precision Touchpad drivers for specific touchpad brands are floating around on the internet).